# Concatenating Strings in Java

Tags: java, string, operator-overloading, string-concatenation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does + work with Strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464330/why-does-work-with-strings-in-java)

The following statements are valid in Java.

```
int a=50;
String tmp="a = ";
String b=tmp+a;
```

`b` of type String now contains `a = 50` (as a String).

Although `tmp` is of type String and `a` is of type `int`, the concatenation is made (even though Java doesn't support operator overloading).

One of the reasons why Java doesn't support operator overloading (as with other languages. In fact, I have no depth knowledge of any language).

> Java does not support operator overloading. Operator overloading is sometimes a source of 
>   ambiguity in C++ program, and the Java design team felt that it causes more trouble than 
>   benefit.

[More](http://linuxostutorial.blogspot.in/2011/08/why-java-does-not-support-operator.html) about it.

How is this statement `String b=tmp+a;` evaluated? There must be some equivalent concept of *Operator Overloading* internally.

---

**Just one question :** Can we see **literally** how it's implemented or we should just believe "*It's just a feature of the language*"?

I have heard that the Java compiler uses `StringBuilder/StringBuffer` (with the `append()` method) to achieve this but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: [+ operator for strings in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2328483/471214) and [Why does + work with Strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5464330/471214)

Comment: It's just built into the compiler as a special case; it's nothing that could be generalized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically this is just a different operator that happens to have the same symbol.  It's the "*string concatenation operator*"; see [section 15.18.1 of the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1).

Regarding implementation, the JLS has this to say:

> An implementation may choose to perform conversion and concatenation
>   in one step to avoid creating and then discarding an intermediate
>   `String` object. To increase the performance of repeated string
>   concatenation, a Java compiler may use the `StringBuffer` class or a
>   similar technique to reduce the number of intermediate `String` objects
>   that are created by evaluation of an expression.
>
> For primitive types, an implementation may also optimize away the
>   creation of a wrapper object by converting directly from a primitive
>   type to a string.

Comment: `tmp+a`==`new StringBuilder().append(tmp).append(a).toString();`? As mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328483/operator-for-string-in-java).

Comment: @Tiny: Yes, the JLS allows the implementation to do something like that (although I guess it would be more like `new StringBuilder(tmp).append(a.toString())`).

Answer (score 2):

Java doesn't allow *user-defined* operator overloading. The language specification gets to define whatever operators it wants :)

And yes, you can see how it's done internally - use `javap -c` to disassembly the class. For example, on my machine your code compiles to:

```
   0: bipush        50
   2: istore_1
   3: ldc           #2    // String a =
   5: astore_2
   6: new           #3    // class java/lang/StringBuilder
   9: dup
  10: invokespecial #4    // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
  13: aload_2
  14: invokevirtual #5    // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
  17: iload_1
  18: invokevirtual #6    // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(I)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
  21: invokevirtual #7    // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
  24: astore_3
  25: return
```

Some details are implementation-specific though; in particular, the Sun/Oracle compiler *used* to use `StringBuffer`, but now uses `StringBuilder` where available.

Comment: `tmp+a`==`new StringBuilder().append(tmp).append(a).toString();`? As mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328483/operator-for-string-in-java).

Comment: @Tiny: In this case, yes. But it doesn't have to be. It's implementation-specific.

Comment: See blog post here on the subject http://www.rationaljava.com/2015/02/the-optimum-method-to-concatenate.html

Answer (score -1):

**Edit: Even the compiler doing this change (that I didn't know), using String concatenations is SLOWER then using StringBuilder.** (Wrong => *No, the compiler does not use StringBuilder/StringBuffer*). You can test it just creating a simple benchmark. The + operator ir "overloaded" in Java for Strings, but the language does not support operator overload.

Try something like this to test the StringBuilder/StringBuffer thing:

```
String str = "";
StringBuffer sbf = new StringBuffer();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

int nTests = 100;
int nConcats = 1000;

long initialTime = 0L;
long afterStrTime = 0L;
long afterSbfTime = 0L;
long afterSbTime = 0L;

for ( int i = 0; i < nTests; i++ ) {

    initialTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    str = "";
    sbf = new StringBuffer();
    sb = new StringBuilder();

    for ( int j = 0; j < nConcats; j++ ) {
        str += "foo"; // or str = str + "foo"
    }
    afterStrTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for ( int j = 0; j < nConcats; j++ ) {
        sbf.append( "foo" );
    }
    afterSbfTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for ( int j = 0; j < nConcats; j++ ) {
        sb.append( "foo" );
    }
    afterSbTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

}

System.out.printf( "%d milliseconds to perform %d concatenations on String\n", afterStrTime - initialTime, nConcats );
System.out.printf( "%d milliseconds to perform %d concatenations on StringBuilder\n", afterSbfTime - afterStrTime, nConcats );
System.out.printf( "%d milliseconds to perform %d concatenations on StringBuffer\n",  afterSbTime - afterSbfTime, nConcats );
```

You will see that StringBuilder can be faster than StringBuffer, since it is not synchronized (StringBuffer is), and both are faster than String.

Comment: You can test it by compiling the code given in the question and then running `javap -c` on it, which *clearly* shows it using `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @JonSkeet, ok, but can you explain why in my code above the String concatenations is not fast as StringBuffer one? If the compiler changes to StringBuffer, the execution should be equaly fast don't you agree?

Comment: Because it instantiates one StringBuilder for each iteration of the loop, and you only instantiate it once.

Comment: So, even changing, it is slower. It is not the same to say that concatenating strings is the same to append in StringBuffer.

Comment: `tmp+a`==`new StringBuilder().append(tmp).append(a).toString();`? As mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328483/operator-for-string-in-java).

Comment: @davidbuzatto: No-one claimed that concatenating strings *in a loop* would be the same as using `StringBuilder`/`StringBuffer`. It still has to produce a `String` object as the result of each iteration. But if you have a single expression with multiple concatenations in: `String a = x + "foo" + y + z;` that will generally use a single `StringBuilder`/`StringBuffer`.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Hi Jon. I know. I just tried to improve my answer to explain something for the OP and for the readers. I know that the answer was wrong.